# Change tyre size on mk1 Ford Ka

Tags: ford, wheels, ka

I've got a 2003 mk1 Ford Ka Style, 1.3 l.
It's currently using tyres sized 165/65/R13 which, in my opinion, are really too thin. Looking around I've seen that it can also mount tyres sized 195/45/R15, which seem to be a popular choice combined with alloy wheels.
I couldn't care less about alloy wheels, all I'm interested in is using thicker tyres.

Will them make any difference in term of stability? Will I be able to fit them with normal steel wheels?
Thank you.

Edit: I'm trying to get the best reliability in wet conditions, that's what I mean by stability. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Looks good ... deleting comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wider is not necessarily better in wet conditions. A wider tire can hydroplane easier. As you will see below, there will be 1.2" width increase. Not sure that will have a negative impact overall in wet conditions.

Below are the differences you will see.

[image]

The primary changes will be;

1. Purchase 15" wheels (steel or alloy) to accommodate the tire size
2. Being aware of the small amount of speedometer error related to the
   overall tire circumference changing the revolutions per mile

[image]

[source](https://tiresize.com/comparison/)

Comment: Ah yes, I've seen that chart you just posted, it's really helpful to see the actual differences between different sizes. I know I'll be losing a bit of sidewall, but will it make any difference? All I'm looking for is trying to increase my car reliability in wet conditions. More than stability I should talk about traction, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I've updated my answer related to wet conditions.

Comment: Great answer. Is the insert from an app?

Comment: @CharlieRB I didn't actually know a wider tyre might worsen hydroplaning. It looks like it's not worth the effort, is it?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 No, it's from [the website he provided as source](https://tiresize.com/comparison/).

Comment: If your primary concern is wet conditions, it may not. I would focus on a better tread pattern that is designed for wet conditions.